# Notify Registration to friends

Tags: algorithm, search

I'm building a system where each user has some contacts (i.e. address book, basically his phone's addressbook).
For example.

Say user `A` has `[X, Y, Z]` in his contacts .

User `B` has `[M, N, O, X]` contacts and `C` has `[D, X, E, F]` contacts.

At this point `A`, `B` and `C` are already registered.

Now when user `X` registers to my system, I want `A`, `B` and `C` to get notified.

A naive approach to this would be to linearly traverse every user's friend list and see which user has `X` in his friend list. But at a large scale this approach would prove to be too costly.

So my question is, can you think of an efficient way through which I can know `A`, `B` and `C` have `X` as a contact ?

**P.S.** All the user identifiers `A`, `B`, `X`, etc. are phone numbers.

Comment: How can A have X as a friend before X registers?

Comment: Right now, you have a map from user to contacts. Can you make a reverse map from contacts to users? That would be memory-intensive, but should work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are already storing phone numbers and contacts somewhere. It shouldn't be too difficult to create a database of **unregistered users'** friends. Then you could just look them up by phone number and notify their friends when they register (and delete their entries). If *a* adds *x* to their contacts and *x* is not a registered user, add *a* to *x*'s entry in the unregistered users database.